# FirstOrCreate no inserta Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

**Hola** estoy insertanto datos por medio de un archivo `excel` y estoy implementando el metodo `firstOrCreate` para una de mis tablas, el problema es que no me inserta los datos.

```
 public function model(array $row)
{



    //TABLA INSTRUMENTOS
    $tipo = tbl_tipo_instrumento::firstOrCreate([
        'tipo_nombre' => $row[14]
    ]);
    $marca = tbl_marca::firstOrCreate([
        'mar_nombre' => $row[15]
    ]);
    $id = Auth::id(); //trae el id del usuario logeado


    return new tbl_instrumentos([
        'ins_codigo'   => $row[0],
        'ins_observacionInicial'   => $row[4],
        'ins_claseOexactitud'    => $row[6],
        'ins_nSerie' => $row[1],
        'ins_divOescala'=>$row[5],
        'ins_claseOexactitud' =>$row[6] ,
        'ins_consecutivoInterno' => $row[7],
        'ins_observaciones' =>$row[8],
        'ins_observacionFinal' => $row[9],
        'ins_magnitud' => $row[10],
        'ins_modelo' => $row[11],
        'ins_codActividad' => $row[12],
        'ins_area' => 'null',
        'ins_usu_id' =>  $id,
        'ins_tipo_id' => $tipo->tipo_id,
        'ins_mar_id' => $marca->mar_id,
    ]);


}
```

Ese es el codigo que estoy usando y mi modelo es el siguiente:

```
class tbl_marca extends Model
{
use Authenticatable;

public $timestamps = false;
public $table="tbl_marca";
protected $primaryKey = 'mar_id';
protected $fillable = [ 'mar_nombre'];

}
```

Si yo ingreso los datos manualmente en `phpmyadmin` los busca sin problemas, en `$row[15] y $row[14]` estan los nombres de cada uno. ¿Cual podria ser el fallo?  Estoy usando `laravel 6`

Gracias

Comment: Si no inserta los datos, entonces ¿ qué comportamiento tiene ese código al momento?

Comment: El comportamiento que tiene es que al parecer el id de la marca hace como si lo registrara y aumenta el id cada vez que hago el import, pero cuando voy a mi base de datos no hay ningun dato registrado

Comment: Tengo entendido que busca el dato y si no lo encuentra lo inserta no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se supone que el método `firstOrCreate` recibe una matriz de vectores donde:

- El primer vector es el valor a buscar *(`first`)*
- El segundo vector es el valor a insertar si el primero no fue encontrado *(`create`)*

Entonces considero deberías redactarlo así:

```
$data = Model::firstOrCreate(
            ['tipo_nombre' => $row[14]],
            ['columna1' => 'valor 1', 'columnaN' => 'valor N']
        );
```

Donde:

- Le indicamos que busque el valor que obtienes en `$row[14]` que se corresponde a la columna o propiedad `tipo_nombre`
- En caso de que lo anterior no retorne algún valor entonces hacemos la inserción de los valores a cada una de las respectivas columnas

> Solo modifica el `create` con las columnas o valores que según sea el caso se requieran

Comment: Mi tabla tipo solo tiene dos campos, un `id` autoincremental y `tipo_nombre`, en ese caso donde pones `columna1` pondria `tipo_nombre=>$row[14]` Así?

Comment: Como no conozco tu tabla entonces considera esto, en el primer vector pones el valor que quieres encontrar, mientras que en el segundo si no encuentras dicho valor entonces procedes a insertar los valores donde yo puse columna1..... @RafaelMonroyRodriguez

Comment: Okey lo hice de ese modo y me paso igual, el id de marca lo aumenta cada vez que hago import y en tipo simplemente no hace nada, igualmente miro en mi base de datos y no se registra nada

Comment: `$tipo = tbl_tipo_instrumento::firstOrCreate(
            ['tipo_nombre' => $row[14]],
            ['tipo_nombre'=>$row[14]]
        );`  Lo hice de esa manera

Comment: Tenia un fallo y era que en mi modelo no tenia referenciada la llave primaria, con eso se soluciono. Gracias

Comment: Oye disculpa `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tipo_nombre' cannot be null (SQL: insert into 'tbl_tipo_instrumento' ('tipo_nombre') values (?))` Porque me sale ese error, estoy seguro que la celda que llamo si esta disponible.

Comment: @RafaelMonroyRodriguez por que no le estás mandando ningún valor, lo que debes hacer es verificar con `dd()` para corroborar lo que recibe, en consecuencia actuar para revisar; es decir dicha variable esta llegando vacía

Comment: Disculpa donde pongo ese `dd( ) ` lo que se me hace raro es que antes me funcionaba perfecto

Comment: prueba colocarlo antes de tu `INSERT` con la variable por dentro para que veas si esta o no llegando algún valor

Comment: Ya lo hice y el dato si llega con el valor de la celda

Comment: @RafaelMonroyRodriguez verifica si dicha columna que te esta marcando como `null` esta dada de alta dentro del array de la propiedad `$fillable` en tu modelo

Comment: Lo tengo así en mi modelo `protected $fillable = ['tipo_nombre'];`

Comment: Al momento no se me ocurre alguna solución, detallando el problema sería bueno que lo publiques como pregunta y esperes que alguno de los otros usuarios de la etiqueta de Laravel te apoyen amigo